# When writing a vim plugin, how to be prepared for the user's custom mappings?

Tags: vim

I'm writing my first vim plugin. In the code I keep using stuff like `execute 'normal k3yy'` but, there is a possibility that the person using the plugin mapped different behaviour to the `k` and `yy` keys for instance, which can lead my plugin to perform in a unexpected way.

How can I avoid this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `normal! k3yy` with `!`

from help doc:

```
If the [!] is given, mappings will not be used.
```